# How to Save io.BytesIO pdfrw PDF into Django FileField

Tags: python, django, pdf, bytesio, pdfrw

What I am trying to do is basically:

1. Get PDF from URL
2. Modify it via pdfrw
3. Store it in memory as
   a BytesIO obj
4. Upload it into a Django FileField via
   `Model.objects.create(form=pdf_file, name="Some name")`

My issue is that when the `create()` method runs, it saves all of the fields *except* for the `form`.

**helpers.py**

```
import io
import tempfile
from contextlib import contextmanager

import requests
import pdfrw


@contextmanager
def as_file(url):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pdf') as tfile:
        tfile.write(requests.get(url).content)
        tfile.flush()
        yield tfile.name


def write_fillable_pdf(input_pdf_path, output_pdf_path, data_dict):
    template_pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader(input_pdf_path)

    ## PDF is modified here

    buf = io.BytesIO()
    print(buf.getbuffer().nbytes). # Prints "0"!
    pdfrw.PdfWriter().write(buf, template_pdf)
    buf.seek(0)
    return buf
```

**views.py**

```
from django.core.files import File

class FormView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_url = 'http://some-pdf-url.com'

        with as_file(form_url) as temp_form_path:
            submitted_form = write_fillable_pdf(temp_form_path, temp_form_path, {"name": "John Doe"})
            print(submitted_form.getbuffer().nbytes).  # Prints "994782"!
            FilledPDF.objects.create(form=File(submitted_form), name="Test PDF") 
        return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

As you can see, `print()` gives out two different values as the BytesIO is populated, leading me to believe the increase in size means there is actually data in it. Is there a reason it is not saving properly into my django model instance? Also, if anyone knows a more efficient way to do this, please let me know!

Answer (score 11):

You can use `ContentFile` class in your code. I did modification accordingly in your view to save your file in filefield.

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

class FormView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_url = 'http://some-pdf-url.com'

        with as_file(form_url) as temp_form_path:
            submitted_form = write_fillable_pdf(temp_form_path, temp_form_path, {"name": "John Doe"})
            pdf_content = ContentFile(submitted_form.getvalue(), 'sample.pdf')
            FilledPDF.objects.create(form=pdf_content, name="Test PDF") 
        return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

You can also use the `save` method to store file using the `ContentFile` class.

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

    class FormView(View):
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form_url = 'http://some-pdf-url.com'

            with as_file(form_url) as temp_form_path:
                submitted_form = write_fillable_pdf(temp_form_path, temp_form_path, {"name": "John Doe"})
                pdf_content = ContentFile(submitted_form.getvalue())
                filled_pdf = FilledPDF()
                filled_pdf.name = "Test PDF"
                filled_pdf.form.save("sample.pdf", pdf_content, save=False)
                filled_pdf.save()
            return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work :( My model instance saves, but the "form" field shows no uploaded files

Comment: @Hybrid, Forgot to add filename in `ContentFile` instance. Update it and also added another way to store file. This will work. :)

Comment: Thank you! It looks like the file wasn't saving the normal way because I forgot the file name.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the documentation on [how to save a file to an object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/file/#additional-methods-on-files-attached-to-objects).

```
from django.core.files import File

filled_pdf = FilledPDF()
filled_pdf.form.save('test_pdf.pdf', File(submitted_form.getvalue()), save=True)
```